# Mutt through PHP, Could Not Send Message

Tags: apache2, php, lamp, mutt

I'm running a small LAMP server on ubuntu. At some point, I need a php script to send an email using Mutt. I use a system call from the php script like this

```
mutt -s $file1 -a threedplot.jpeg -a velocityvstime.jpeg -a elossperstep.jpeg -a input.txt -a output.txt -- $email < /var/www/html/emailmessage.txt
```

Where all the variables and files are appropriately defined (This line is in runner.sh). When I execute the command from the command line as ubuntu user, there's no problem and the email is sent. But when the php tries executing it with a system call,

```
$last_line = system("./runner.sh Queued/", $retval);
```

it just says "Could not send the message". I suspect that this is because the php runs on the www-data user, which may not have the proper permissions. Is there a way to add the www-data user so it has full access to Mutt? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that when mutt tries to send the message, it also tries to save it in a sent folder. As it is running as web-user/www user/apache user or similar, this fails. The fix is to use a local mutt config file (specified with -F on your mutt line) and make sure `set copy=no` is in that config file.

thanks to kenene on [ubuntu formum archive](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1243547.html)
for this.